# Conditional Formatting in Datatables using _TOTAL_

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, datatables

I had a small annoyance with Datatables recently, I changed the `sInfo` attribute of `oLanguage`, to `"There are _TOTAL_ people in this Role."`

If I have 2 or more entries, this is fine, but on the common occurence of this table having one entry, I end up with "There are 1 people in this Role" - it looks terrible.

So my question is, **is there any way to get the value of the `_TOTAL_` attribute and use an alternative string with JQuery Datatables?**

Here is the full code sample:

```
$("#sqepMatrix").dataTable({
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "bPaginate": false,
        "oLanguage": {
            "sInfo": "There are _TOTAL_ people in this Role."
        },
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers"
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure it out!

Using the *[fnInfoCallback](https://datatables.net/ref#fnInfoCallback)* attribute I can evaluate the `iTotal` attribute and based on the if statement shown below, I can decide what string to puke out!

Usage:

```
$("#sqepMatrix").dataTable({
    "bJQueryUI": true,
    "bPaginate": false,

    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "fnInfoCallback": function (oSettings, iTotal) {
        if (iTotal == 1) {
            return "There is one person in this Role.";
        }
        else {
            return "There are " + iTotal + " people in the Role.";
        }
    }
});
```